# How to query conversions per consumer grouped by ad frequency in SSAS?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I have two fact tables:

1. Display_Ad_Impressions
2. Web_Site_Clicks

One of the measure fields in `Web_Site_Clicks` is `Conversion`. This is `TRUE` when the page is the "Order_Confirmed" page.

I have a Customers dimension that is shared by the two fact tables.

What `MDX` query would return the average number of conversions per consumer, grouped by the number of ad impressions viewed by the consumer?

Or is this only possible by integrating these two fact tables into a single Events fact table that includes both display ad impressions and web site clicks?  If so, what would the `MDX` look like?

Comment: @kenArcher sounds like a potentially interesting question but in its current state it might be worth adding the tag "telepathy" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Feeling around in the dark as we currently have very little idea of dimensions and hierarchies within your cube.

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[ConversionCount] AS 
 Sum(
   [Customers].[Customers].[Customers], 
   Iif([Measures].[Conversion] = "TRUE",1,0))
MEMBER [Measures].[AvgDailyConversionCount] AS
 Sum(
   [Date].[Date].[Date], 
   [Measures].[ConversionCount]
 )
SELECT
  [Measures].[AvgDailyConversionCount] ON 0,
  [ad impressions].[ad impressions].[ad impressions] ON 1 //<<this groups by Ad impressions
FROM   [YourCube];
```